# Want to get an address in google maps from Long and Latitude and print on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got this JavaScript that allows me to take long and latitude and place my google maps center on this and a marker on it as well.

I've been searching google for a while, and i can't find a place that shows me how to attach an address(as specific as possible) to the marker. I want to find an address from the long and latitude.

Is there anyone that has a smart way to do this?

Here is the code i have for now, which does the things i stated above.

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.653363,12.547604);
    // set the options for zoom level and map type
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    // create a map in the map_canvas div element
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.setCenter(latlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: latlng
            });
}
```

I have more code, and i can post the full JS, but not sure that it is needed. If it is, let me know :)

Oh - I just found this following code:

```
public List<Address> getAddress() {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
            if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude ,
                        longitude, 1);
                        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                        Log.d("TAG", "address = "+address+", city ="+city+", country = "+country    );
            return addresses;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "latitude and longitude are null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But I am extremely beginner level on JS, so i have no idea how to convert this into my JS! Hopefully someone can help me out :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use the `Reverse Geocoding` of [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), **Note**: `Reverse geocoding` is an estimate. The geocoder will attempt to find the `closest addressable location within a certain tolerance`. If no match is found, the geocoder will return zero results.

Comment: As what Kyojimaru said but heres another [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) which might help.

Comment: @BG101 Am i correct in saying ,that it seems the Geocoding API costs money to use? Just need to be sure, or am I mistaken here? :)